# Is it possible to use dynamic variables inside a const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I have a feeling this is a silly question but is it possible to use dynamic variables inside the following code:

```
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState ({
    latitude:-8.683895,
    longitude:115.152307,
    width:800,
    height:440,
    zoom:16
});
```

I need the latitude and longitude to be dynamic, so something like the following:

```
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState ({
    latitude:{varLatitude),
    longitude:{varLongitude},
    width:800,
    height:440,
    zoom:16
});
```

What would be the correct way to do this, please?
Cheers!

Comment: Why the brackets? Just define a variable and use it without the brackets?

Comment: Well the short answer is yes, you can change state values to whatever you want (using the approach state setting methods). It might help if you provide more info about your use case, this is a little vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply defining variable you don't need to to add bracket:

```
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState ({
   latitude:varLatitude,
   longitude:varLongitude,
   width:800,
   height:440,
   zoom:16
 });
```